# Онлайн-игра "Морской бой" на Python.

Tags: python, разработка-игр

Я бы хотел создать игру "Морской бой" на Python с возможностью играть по сети. Я уже создал код для игры по очереди с одной клавиатуры. Хотелось бы узнать, какие библиотеки или фреймворки лучше всего подойдут для реализации сетевой версии игры? Для создания графического интерфейса хочу использовать Tkinter. Для передачи данных по сети думал воспользоваться библиотекой socket, но не знаю достаточно ли этого.

Comment: Да, этого достаточно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Игра «Морской бой»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9_(%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0)) сводится по сути к простому диалогу:

```
Алиса: Ж7 
Боб:   Потопил!
Алиса: Д1
Боб:   Мимо!
Боб:   А1
Алиса: Ранил!
Боб: ...
```

Поэтому требования к задержке, к пропускной способности сети — минимальны. Нет необходимости высчитывать состояние игры на сервере или предсказывать действия других игроков на клиенте в ожидании ответа от сервера с действительным состоянием.

В силу простоты, можно напрямую соединять игроков без сервера, что может позволить играть без интернета, по локальной сети (к примеру, обнаруживая игроков, используя Bonjour/mDNS), или Bluetooth, или Wi-fi Direct или даже [ультра](https://www.anfractuosity.com/projects/ultrasound-via-a-laptop/)[звук](http://smus.com/ultrasonic-networking/).

С точки зрения игры, достаточно определить две функции, которые могут посылать/получать сообщения: `send()` и `recv()`  соответственно, тогда основной цикл игры может выглядеть так:

```
async def game(player, send, recv):
    # ... send, receive board hmac

    # the first shot
    if player.has_first_move():
        shot = await player.next_shot()
        await send(shot)
    else:
        shot = None

    # main loop
    tracking_board = Board()
    while True:
        board.display() # update GUI
        reply = await recv()
        if shot:  # we've fired a shot
            tracking_board.mark(shot, reply)
            if reply in {HIT, DEAD}:
                if reply == DEAD:
                    if tracking_board.game_over():
                        # ... cleanup
                        await send(str(board)) # for verification
                        break
                shot = await player.next_shot()
                await send(shot)
            elif answer == MISS:
                shot = None
        elif shot is None:  # we are under attack
            damage = board.find_damage(reply) # reply is a position
            await send(damage) # send HIT, MISS, DEAD
            if damage == MISS:  # our turn
                shot = await player.next_shot()
                await send(shot)
            elif damage == DEAD and board.game_over():
                board_string = await recv()  # for verification
                break
    # ... verify that tracking_board matches board hmac
```

Здесь используется простой протокол, где все объекты как текст передаются, по одному на строчку. В качестве альтернативы, можно принимать/отсылать объекты в json формате. `recv()`, `send()` функции можно к примеру так создать:

```
def create_recv_send(reader, writer):
    async def send(s):
        return writer.write((s + '\n').encode())
        await writer.drain()

    async def recv():
        data = await reader.readline()
        return data.decode().rstrip('\n')
    return recv, send
```

где reader, writer в свою очередь могут представлять интерактивный ввод/вывод, сокеты, итд. Вот пример, использующий tcp/ip соединения:

```
import asyncio
import socket

async def main():
    port = int.from_bytes(b'SB', 'big')  # SB stands for Sea Battle
    host = socket.gethostname() + '.local'  # Zeroconf

    async def second_player():
        reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host, port)
        await game(Player(has_first_move=False), *create_recv_send(reader, writer))
        writer.close()

    async def play_game():
        done = asyncio.Event()

        async def callback(reader, writer):
            await game(Player(), *create_recv_send(reader, writer))
            writer.close()
            done.set()

        server = await asyncio.start_server(callback, host, port)
        await asyncio.wait([done.wait(), second_player()],
                           return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        server.close()

    await play_game()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Здесь оба игрока в одном процессе, но в общем случае, при запуске на разных устройствах, только `first_player()` либо `second_player()` вызываются. Для демонстрации, что подход работает для сетевой версии, вот [полный пример игры в терминале](https://gist.github.com/zed/ee60cb1ab71ac10e3ad281e7ef1790a3) (без человеческого участия, выстрелы случайно выбираются, не учитывая историю):

[image: battleship game tty]

Обозначения:

- `S` — корабль
- `/` — промах
- `X` — попадание
- `D` — утоплен