# Как реализовать взаимодействие двух игроков через терминал?

Tags: python, разработка-игр, сетевое-программирование

Есть одна игра в терминале, написанная на Python — крестики-нолики. Реализована она так, что после каждой команды высвечивается символ — крестик или нолик. Игра сделана "на двоих", то есть команда1 — нолик, команда2 — крестик и так далее, до победы. Все условия записаны, но нужно прикрутить туда сетевую часть, но я совсем не понимаю как это сделать. Статьи из сети помогли только разобраться что это такое, но как это прикрутить к своему приложению или вообще любому действию я не понимаю.

Взаимодействие должно происходить так:

- игрок подключается к другому игроку
- игрок1 вводит команду, отправляя все свои файлы (или их состояние) игроку2 и игроку1 блокируется клавиатура для ввода команд
- игрок2 делает то же самое
- после некоторого условия взаимодействие должно прерваться

Comment: Думаю, нужно смотреть в сторону клиент-серверной архитектуры. Можно посмотреть модуль socket. Вот, например, [небольшая статья](https://habr.com/post/149077/) про его использование

Comment: Думаю вам поможет: https://github.com/Frodox/tic-tac-toe-game или хотя бы будете иметь представление о ```socket```, и как сказал Alexshev92 - посмотрите в сторону Client-Server...

Comment: [сетевой морской бой в терминале](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/724373/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю реализовать в виде REST API. Таким образом можно играть как через браузер, так и через терминал консольными браузерами или даже загружать страницу командой curl.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```